# Django Celery Error When Starting CeleryBeat - Cannot Add Item To Database

Tags: celery, django-celery

I've set up a Django project through Apache using mod_wsgi, and I'm now trying to add django-celery to the mix to run periodic and scheduled tasks.  I'm running into occasional error messages, though, but I haven't found an explanation for what they mean.

When I start up Celerybeat using:

```
./manage.py celery beat
```

I often get one of the two following errors:

```
Message Error: cannot add item to database

celerybeat raised exception <class 'dbm.error'>: error('cannot add item to database',)
```

I can see that celerybeat generates two files in the project directory: celerybeat-schedule.dir and celerybeat-schedule.pag.  I'm pretty sure these files are the "database" mentioned in the error message.  If I delete these files, Celerybeat will usually run without problems for a couple times, but then the errors come back.

Is there something that I need to do with the celerybeat-schedule files to avoid this error?  I thought it might be a permissions issue, but I couldn't see any issues.

Comment: remove this file: celerybeat-schedule.db

Answer (score 26):

just rm celerybeat.db, and start you celerybeat again will work

Comment: This worked. Seems what I did wrong was to purge running beat instance in htop using SIGKILL. But I when used SIGTERM, no such issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by installing `python3-gdbm` (or `python3-dbm`) package and re-creating schedule file.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue and was not able to figure it out.

A workaround is to use the database to store the schedules:

`celery -A proj beat -S djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler`

You'll need to `pip install django-celery` and update your database if you go this route.